# XML has multiple value nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, treenode

Updated: I can only step down to the first value node in my XML. 
The code below gets to the first value node and shows data, but how would I select another node? I only need 3 values at the moment from each item node.The Tax Year, Bill number, and appl_amt, along with the image path are the only values I am working on retrieving. The Xml added is only a portion. The section added repeats several times until the BatchCompiler/Batch/transactions/transaction tags close the groupings.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <BatchCompiler>
<batch>
   <batchid>95531</batchid>
   <transactions>
        <transaction>
            <items>
              <item>
                <values>
                  <value>
                     <name>doc_type</name>
                     <data>1</data> 
                  </value>
                  <value>
                    <name>doc_id</name>
                    <data>10</data>
                 </value>
                   <value>
                    <name>Bill Base Number</name>
                    <data>0007956700</data>
                 </value>
                 <value>
                    <name>Tax Year</name>
                    <data>2015</data>
                </value>
                 <value>
                    <name>Year For</name>
                    <data>2015</data> 
               </value>
                <value>
                   <name>Listing Type</name>
                   <data>0000</data>
              </value>
               <value>
                  <name>Postmark Date</name>
                   <data>08212015</data>
             </value>
            <value>
                   <name>appl_amt</name>
                   <data>18.12</data>
            </value>
            <value>
                    <name>tran_num</name>
                    <data>1</data>
           </value>
           <value>
                   <name>tran_seq</name>
                   <data>1</data>
           </value>
          </values>
          <image>..\images\95531_1_S_1.tif</image>
     </item>

 namespace GETZIP2
 {
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("\\example\\index.xml);  
        MessageBox.Show(doc.SelectSingleNode("BatchCompiler/batch/transactions/transaction/items/item/values/value").InnerText);

    }

    }

 }
```

Comment: SelectSingleNode is a self-speaking method name, isn't it?

Comment: Take a look at `LINQ to XML`.

Comment: You would be far better off by using attributes: `<value name="doc_type" data="1" />` which is a lot less lines.

Comment: @user9993 yea, I was thinking that, may have to see if I can get this file reformatted.

Comment: See answer 2 on following webpage.  Used it a lot : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to XML is a much better API than the old `XmlDocument` DOM, and LINQ to XML's query methods a lot nicer than messing around with XPath.

Something like this would probably work, though it would help if you showed some XML and were a little more specific about which values you actually want.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"\example\index.xml");

foreach (var value in doc.Descendants("value"))
{
    var name = (string)value.Element("name");
    var data = (string)value.Element("data");

    // do something with these
}
```

If you wanted to query for a specific key/value pair, you could do something like:

```
var taxYear = doc.Descendants("value")
    .Where(e => (string)e.Element("name") == "Tax Year")
    .Select(e => (string)e.Element("data")
    .Single();
```

You might even consider creating a dictionary of all key/value pairs:

```
var keyValues = doc.Descendants("value")
    .ToDictionary(e => (string)e.Element("name"), e => (string)e.Element("data"));

var taxYear = keyValues["TaxYear"];
var billNumber = keyValues["Bill Base Number"];
```

Comment: Thanks, i have added XML and info about the values I am working on

Comment: @drummerORcoder I've updated to include some more specifics following the addition of your XML.

Comment: When I attempt to use the dictionary method, I receive a 'System.ArgumentException' : An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: I can't seem to get around the fact that all the values are in identically named elements("name"/"data")

Comment: @drummerORcoder that's not likely to be the issue as the code would work with the (partial) XML you posted. I would guess your XML has multiple `item` elements and each contain `value` elements with the same `name`.  Perhaps you could iterate each `item` using `doc.Descendants("item")` and then create a dictionary from each of these.

Answer (score -1):

Besides Linq to XML, you can also use `XmlReader` class. It offers functions like `ReadToNextSibling` which help you move through siblings.

Other functions such as `ReadToDescendant` and `MoveToNextAttribute` might come in handy.

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"\example\index.xml");

// Move to the desired element.
reader.MoveToContent();
reader.ReadToDescendant("value");
```

Comment: Some XML elements are not content node. This function continue reading elements until it reaches a content node, then it will return that node as `XmlNodeType` object. [More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.movetocontent(v=vs.110).aspx)