# Getting list of all nodes in XML

Tags: c#, xml, powershell

I'm trying to iterate through each node in an XML document. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I'm doing this in PowerShell, but could translate from C#.

```psh
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem ($directoryUrl+"\*.*") -include *.xml)
{
    [xml]$xmlFile = Get-Content $file; #get content from xml file
    Write-Host "Fff";

    $firstNode = $xmlFile.DocumentElement;

    $children = $firstNode.ChildNodes;
```

Now this gets the children of the first, node which is fine, but it's picking up `Random` as a child, but I also want it to pick up what's inside the `Random` XML tag. Like in the details tags.

How can I get this easily in PowerShell?

The XML I'm reading is:

```xml
<UserBase> 
  <User> 
    <Name>Kalle</Name> 
  </User> 
  <User> 
    <Name>Becker</Name> 
  </User>
  <User> 
    <Name>Daniel</Name> 
  </User> 
  <User> 
    <Name>Anderson</Name> 
  </User>
  <Random>
    <Details>myself</Details>
    <Details>mysdelf</Details>
  </Random>
</UserBase>
```

Comment: To handle multilevel xml you need to use a recursive function.  Try AddNode in answer 2 on following webpage.  A TreeView is a good way of display an xml file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Comment: What do you mean by AddNode?

Comment: It is part of answer #2 on the webpage

Comment: What about the child nodes of the `<User>` nodes? i.e. do you actually want a list of *all* nodes (including text nodes?), or just specific nodes (which?)?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I really understand your question, but to get all nodes from an XML document, you can call XPath to the rescue:

```
$xml = [xml] @"
    <UserBase> 
      <User> 
        <Name>Kalle</Name> 
      </User> 
      <User> 
        <Name>Becker</Name> 
      </User>
      <User> 
        <Name>Daniel</Name> 
      </User> 
      <User> 
        <Name>Anderson</Name> 
      </User>
      <Random>
        <Details>myself</Details>
        <Details>mysdelf</Details>
      </Random>
    </UserBase>
"@

select-xml $xml -xpath "/descendant-or-self::node()" | 
   where { !$_.Node.Name.Contains("#") }
```