# Add a parent node to the child nodes in an XML

Tags: xml, recursion

I had a very simple problem but am short on time so would be really grateful if anyone can provide the quick answer. Basically I had an XML given below :

```
 <Root>
<Delhi>
    <Population>1000</Population>`enter code here`
</Delhi>
<Mumbai>
    <Population>1000</Population>
    <District>
        <Name>Colaba</Name>
    </District>
    <District>
        <Name>navi Mumbai</Name>
    </District>
    <District></District>
</Mumbai>
<Mumbai>
    <Population>1000</Population>
</Mumbai>
<Mumbai>
    <Population>1000</Population>
</Mumbai>
<Chennai>
    <Population>1000</Population>
    <District>
        <Name>Chan</Name>
    </District>
</Chennai>
<Kolkata>
    <Population>1000</Population>
</Kolkata>
```

I want to pass this XML to a method and want a response something like below:

```
<Root>
<Delhi>
    <Population>1000</Population>
</Delhi>
<Mumbai>
    <Mumbai>
        <Population>1000</Population>
        <District>
            <District>
                <Name>Colaba</Name>
            </District>
            <District>
                <Name>navi Mumbai</Name>
            </District>
            <District></District>
        </District>
    </Mumbai>
    <Mumbai>
        <Population>1000</Population>
    </Mumbai>
    <Mumbai>
        <Population>1000</Population>
    </Mumbai>
</Mumbai>
<Chennai>
    <Chennai>
        <Population>1000</Population>
        <District>
            <District>
                <Name>Chan</Name>
            </District>
        </District>
    </Chennai>
</Chennai>
<Kolkata>
    <Population>1000</Population>
</Kolkata>
```

So the logic is very simple : I want to iterate through the nodes of the Root Element and I check if my node is either Mumbai,District or Chennai. If it is, I enclose all the tags by that name inside a tag having the same name. The XML can have any level so I believe it needs to be done through recursion effectively.

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's very hard to help you without knowing which language or XML API you're using - and you should show what you've already tried. Also, if you could show a shorter example, it would help to keep things simple.

Comment: Convert it to a native array. Structure it properly, then convert it back to xml. Tip: you can use json encode and decode to convert to and from array.

Comment: Be aware that if you say you are in a hurry, people are less likely to answer, because they think you're unlikely to give the answer proper consideration.

Comment: 1. I am trying to do it in C#.2. @Pamblam - Unfortunately this is the structure we will receive.

Comment: @Michael Kay - Advice noted

Comment: Yea you mentioned that. Do you understand what "convert" means... good luck getting any help

Comment: Also, post the language next time.

Comment: Used the AddNode code on following webpage lots of times : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Consider an XSLT solution which most general-purpose languages maintain libraries for including Perl, PHP, Python, VB, Java, and C# (among still others). As information, [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) is declarative, special-purpose programming language (same type as SQL is but with databases) used specifically to transform, style, re-format, or re-structure XML documents.

Please note: this XSLT script transforms your XML but does not handle only copies the two extraneous *Mumbai nodes* which seem out of place with your document.

The XSLT uses the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to group the District items together.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="MumbaiDistrict" match="Mumbai[1]" use="District" />
  <xsl:key name="ChennaiDistrict" match="Chennai" use="District" />

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>   

    <xsl:template match="Mumbai[1]">
      <xsl:element name="Mumbai">
        <xsl:element name="Mumbai">        
            <xsl:copy-of select="Population"/>
            <xsl:element name="District">
              <xsl:for-each select="key('MumbaiDistrict', District)">          
                <xsl:copy-of select="District"/>          
             </xsl:for-each>
           </xsl:element>          
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Chennai">
      <xsl:element name="Chennai">
        <xsl:element name="Chennai">
           <xsl:copy-of select="Population"/>
           <xsl:element name="District">
             <xsl:for-each select="key('ChennaiDistrict', District)">          
              <xsl:copy-of select="District"/>          
             </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <Delhi><Population>1000</Population>`enter code here`
</Delhi>
  <Mumbai>
    <Mumbai>
      <Population>1000</Population>
      <District>
        <District>
          <Name>Colaba</Name>
        </District>
        <District>
          <Name>navi Mumbai</Name>
        </District>
        <District/>
      </District>
    </Mumbai>
  </Mumbai>
  <Mumbai>
    <Population>1000</Population>
  </Mumbai>
  <Mumbai>
    <Population>1000</Population>
  </Mumbai>
  <Chennai>
    <Chennai>
      <Population>1000</Population>
      <District>
        <District>
          <Name>Chan</Name>
        </District>
      </District>
    </Chennai>
  </Chennai>
  <Kolkata>
    <Population>1000</Population>
  </Kolkata>
</Root>
```