# Split XML into Strings

Tags: c#, xml, string

I'm looking to split an XML document into a list of strings but I'm totally at a loss.

```
<RISKCALC-OUT>
  <AUTHENTICATION>
    <USERID></USERID>
  </AUTHENTICATION>
  <OPERATION-LIST>
    <OPERATION MODEL="PRV" SUBMODEL="GBR40EDF" VERSION="4.0" FUNCTION="EDFCLC" TARGET="New Platform">
      .......
    </OPERATION>
    <OPERATION MODEL="PRV" SUBMODEL="GBR40EDF" VERSION="4.0" FUNCTION="EDFCLC" TARGET="New Platform">
      .....
    </OPERATION>
  </OPERATION-LIST>
</RISKCALC-OUT>
```

I'm trying to split this file into strings, so that everything below the first operation node is in one string, and then everything below the second operation node is in a second string.

I've been playing around with XmlNodeLists but I haven't got anywhere. I don't need a total answer, just how to separate them ready to put in to separate strings.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show an example result, so it 's not ambiguous and people don't loose searching in the dark. Are these the .... that you expect to see in a first string and same in second string ?

Comment: You *don't* need to separate anything, you need to *select* the Operation nodes, using XPath or LINQ to XML. You can use the `//OPERATION` XPath expression to return all operation nodes, eg with [XmlDocument.SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx). If you use XDocument instead you can type a LINQ query instead of XPath

Comment: Sorry, each operation looks like this: https://gist.github.com/robbiewoods05/0a50ff5d1905e8f1ff83

That's exactly what I'd like each string to look like.

Comment: Look at treeview example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = "XMLFile1.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
    var ops = xdoc.Descendants("OPERATION")
        .Elements()
        .Select(n => n.ToString())
        .ToList<string>();

    ops.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
}
```

I used this sample XML (added random stuff for testing purposes):

```
<RISKCALC-OUT>
  <AUTHENTICATION>
    <USERID></USERID>
  </AUTHENTICATION>
  <OPERATION-LIST>
    <OPERATION MODEL="PRV" SUBMODEL="GBR40EDF" VERSION="4.0" FUNCTION="EDFCLC" TARGET="New Platform">
      <SUBNODES ID="1">
        <ANOTHER ID="56"></ANOTHER>
      </SUBNODES>
    </OPERATION>
    <OPERATION MODEL="PRV" SUBMODEL="GBR40EDF" VERSION="4.0" FUNCTION="EDFCLC" TARGET="New Platform">
      <SUBNODES ID="1">
        <ANOTHER ID="65"></ANOTHER>
      </SUBNODES>
    </OPERATION>
  </OPERATION-LIST>
</RISKCALC-OUT>
```

and got this output with the above code:

```
<SUBNODES ID="1">
  <ANOTHER ID="56"></ANOTHER>
</SUBNODES>
<SUBNODES ID="1">
  <ANOTHER ID="65"></ANOTHER>
</SUBNODES>
```

To keep the OPERATION nodes you can remove Elements() like this:

```
var ops = xdoc.Descendants("OPERATION")
            .Select(n => n.ToString())
            .ToList<string>();
```

which would produce

```
<OPERATION MODEL="PRV" SUBMODEL="GBR40EDF" VERSION="4.0" FUNCTION="EDFCLC" TARGE
T="New Platform">
  <SUBNODES ID="1">
    <ANOTHER ID="56"></ANOTHER>
  </SUBNODES>
</OPERATION>
<OPERATION MODEL="PRV" SUBMODEL="GBR40EDF" VERSION="4.0" FUNCTION="EDFCLC" TARGE
T="New Platform">
  <SUBNODES ID="1">
    <ANOTHER ID="65"></ANOTHER>
  </SUBNODES>
</OPERATION>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use LinQ to Xml.
Maintenance  is easier.

```
XElement xmla = XElement.Load("input.xml");
var results = from operationList in xmla.Descendants("OPERATION")
                select operationList.Value;
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**EDIT to have the best of both worlds**
(Actually there are three worlds here: Object/String and XML)

A class to hold the data :

```
class Operation
{
    public String Model { get; set; }
    public String SubModel { get; set; }
    // and so on ...

    public String TagContent { get; set; }
    public String FullTag{ get; set; }
}
```

Make the linq query :

```
XElement xmla = XElement.Load("input.xml");
var operations = from operation in xmla.Descendants("OPERATION")
                    select new Operation
                    {
                        Model = operation.Attribute("MODEL").Value,
                        SubModel = operation.Attribute("SUBMODEL").Value,
                        TagContent = operation.Value,
                        FullTag = operation.ToString(),

                    };
foreach (var operation in operations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(operation.Model + " - " + operation.SubModel+ " - " + operation.TagContent " - " + operation.FullTag);
}
```

Regards

Comment: This is very close to what I'm after, but I'd like to keep the tags as well... is there any way to do that?

Comment: You want to keep  <OPERATION MODEL="PRV" SUBMODEL="GBR40EDF" VERSION="4.0" FUNCTION="EDFCLC" TARGET="New ...">. or do you want to have all the information in an Operation holding Model, SubModel Information ?

Comment: I'd like to keep every tag including <OPERATION>, <ARGUMENT-LIST>, <ARGUMENT> etc, as well as all the information your first solution gave.

Comment: @Robert : May be the edit above  answers all your wishes