# How to add return plain text from xml web service into data table in c#, mvc

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable, dataset

I have called to a web service which returns plain text of xml web service. What I want is to get that plain text (string) into data table.how can I do that.
this is my code.

```
           WebClient client = new WebClient();
           string url =  string.Format("https://www.someurl/products.ashx");
           string response = client.DownloadString(url);
```

this code retruns the string(plain text) of web service.

Comment: Could you give an example of the xml and the result you want to display?

Comment: this code returns a string as I said. it has xml tags.but it is a plain text. no I want to put that return plain text into a dataset and then to a table.please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication56
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string response = "";
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to display the result in view, do you have any idea how to do that.

Comment: I like using a treeview.  See answer in following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp