# Save loop in XML traversion

Tags: c#, xml

Is it possible to economize the loop in the following code snippet (element is of type XElement)?

```
TreeViewItem root = new TreeViewItem();

foreach (XAttribute attr in element.Attributes()) {
     root.HtmlAttributes.Add(attr.Name.ToString(),attr.Value);
}
```

So that I could pass lists as parameter to the function something like:

```
root.HtmlAttributes(element.Attributes.Names,element.Attributes.Values)
```

Comment: There is [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) with the [`ForEach` extension](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/ForEach.cs).

Comment: See webpage :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Comment: XElement is part of an XML document but your code is using HTML. They are not the same. I'm confused!!!