# Merging a datasets datatables to a single datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

Please assist. I'm struggling a bit with this.This is the xml output of a c# dataset. Its a Quickbooks response loaded into a dataset. I've removed the bulk of data and columns for clarity.

This hierachy, is (table>row>table) relation. I'm trying to get to a single datatable. So table [CustomerRet]+[Adjoining tables] return a single datatable with merged column names.

**COLUMNS**
ListID
Col1
Col2 
BillAddress (another table holding results)
   Addr1
   Addr2
Col

---

Will now return table structure and rows (only need the first row of the adjoined table)

> ListID, Col1, Col2, BillAddressAddr1, BillAddressAddr2, Col6...etc

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<QBXML>
  <xs:schema id="QBXML" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="QBXML" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="QBXMLMsgsRs">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CustomerQueryRs" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="CustomerRet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ListID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="BillAddress" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                              <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                  <xs:element name="Addr1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                  <xs:element name="Addr2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                  <xs:element name="Addr3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                              </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>                            
                          </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>                   
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <QBXMLMsgsRs>
    <CustomerQueryRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
      <CustomerRet>
        <ListID>20000-1197738925</ListID>
        <BillAddress>
          <Addr1>Cristina Andres</Addr1>
          <Addr2>4242 Cypress Hill Rd</Addr2>
        </BillAddress>
      </CustomerRet>
    </CustomerQueryRs>
  </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

```
 //something like
                DataTable dtFinal = new DataTable();
                //Load the Qb Dataset    
                DataSet dsQb = new DataSet();
                dsQb.ReadXml(fileName, XmlReadMode.Auto);
                dtFinal = dsQb.Tables[2].Clone();

                foreach(DataRow dr in dsQb.Tables[2].Rows)
                {
                    //Add the missing columns...?

                }
                //Import the rows
```

Anyone have any pointers? Maybe linq?

Answer (score 0):

The DataSet.ReadXml() doesn't work well when the number of levels of xml children gets too large.  Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq; 

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENANE = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENANE);

            var customerQueryRs = doc.Descendants("CustomerQueryRs").Select(x => new {
                statusCode = x.Attribute("statusCode").Value,
                statusSeverity = x.Attribute("statusSeverity").Value,
                statusMessage = x.Attribute("statusMessage").Value,
                listID = x.Descendants("ListID").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                addresses = x.Descendants("BillAddress").FirstOrDefault().Descendants().Select(y => new {
                    address = y.Value
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thank you :) mmm. Looks interesting. I'll give it a try. My current approach is a bit messy :( and partially works. I'm sure it's easier to mess around with the node list than play inside that dataset. Some of them can get huge. The one prob is, I won't know the name of the columns, but i think i can work around that.

Comment: You may ant to looks at the recursive approach in following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp