# How to parse an arbitrary XML string into a structured object

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string of XML data whose schema is unknown.  I would like to parse it into a tree structure my code can easily peruse.  For example if the string is:

```
<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>
```

I want to be able to access it with code like:

```
elem["foo"]["bar"]
```

and get `baz`.

**EDIT:** The supposed "duplicate" assumes you **do** know the structure / schema of the XML.  As I originally stated, I do **not**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Deserialize XML document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Comment: Not a duplicate - this is about accessing a parsed XML object, not to deserialize into a (strongly typed) class.

Comment: @Donal you can't really deserialize XML to objects if the schema is unknown.

Comment: @CharlesMager, see answer... apparently you can

Comment: Of course, there is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files

Comment: @JoelFan - what answer?

Comment: @CharlesMager - my bad.

Comment: @CharlesMager, he is probably assuming you are the one who added the (incorrect) link to a "possible duplicate"

Comment: See following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

It sounds pretty much like you want what LINQ to XML offers.  Parse XML like so:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>");
```

Then you could query it in a similar way to your suggested syntax:

```
var barValue = (string)doc.Elements("foo").Elements("bar").Single()
```

or:

```
var barValue = (string)doc.Descendants("bar").Single()
```

See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I agree with the other answers that a LINQ to XML based solution is best. Something like:

```
string xml = "<root><foo><bar>baz</bar></foo></root>";
string s = XElement.Parse(xml).Element("foo").Element("bar").Value;
```

But if you *really* wanted behaviour like your example, you could write a small wrapper class such as:

**EDIT: Example updated to be indexable using a [multidimensional indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182152.aspx)<sup><sup>note</sup></sup>.**

```
class MyXmlWrapper
{
    XElement _xml;

    public MyXmlWrapper(XElement xml)
    {
        _xml = xml;
    }

    public MyXmlWrapper this[string name, int index = 0]
    {
        get
        {
            return new MyXmlWrapper(_xml.Elements(name).ElementAt(index));
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MyXmlWrapper xml)
    {
        return xml._xml.Value;
    }
}
```

And use that exactly like you wanted:

```
string xml = "<root><foo><bar>baz</bar></foo></root>";
MyXmlWrapper wrapper = new MyXmlWrapper(XElement.Parse(xml));
string s = wrapper["foo"]["bar"];
```

**Edited example for returning an element from a collection:**

```
string xml = "<root><foo><bar><baz>1</baz><baz>2</baz></bar></foo></root>";
MyXmlWrapper wrapper = new MyXmlWrapper(XElement.Parse(xml));
string baz1 = wrapper["foo"]["bar"]["baz", 0];
string baz2 = wrapper["foo"]["bar"]["baz", 1];
```

Comment: The OP has clarified that he wants to parse arbitrary XML files.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera this does parse arbitrary XML files?

Comment: Not really - we don't know what kind of XML we'll get. For example, you can't get the second `baz` element in `<root><foo><bar><baz>1</baz><baz>2</baz></bar></foo></root>`.

Answer (score 1):

`XDocument.Parse(string)` is your friend:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532(v=vs.110).aspx