# Generate TreeView from XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, treeview

I want create TreeView from data source like XML file. Also I need customize visible Name of element.

What I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<List>


<siteMapNode title="Title1" url="http://example.com/Pages/General.aspx" description="Description1">

   <siteMapNode title="Title2" url="http://example.com/Pages/Base.aspx" description="Description2"/>

</siteMapNode>

<siteMapNode title="Title3" url="http://example.com/Lists/News.aspx" description="Description3"> </siteMapNode>



</List>
```

And it i can generate:

```
List
  siteMapNode
     siteMapNode
  siteMapNode
```

And now what I want get:

```
List
  Title1
    Title2
  Title3
```

**UPD:**
I generate treeview like it in .aspx:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="footerSiteMap.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>

<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Xmldatasource1" ShowLines="true" ShowCheckBoxes="All">

    <DataBindings>
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="{siteMapNode_Id}" TextField="{siteMapNode_Id}" ValueField="{siteMapNode_Id}"  />
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="{siteMapNode_Id_0}" TextField="{siteMapNode_Id_0}" ValueField="{siteMapNode_Id_0}" />
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="{title}" TextField="{title}" ValueField="{title}" />
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="{url}" TextField="{url}" ValueField="{url}" />
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="{description}" TextField="{description}" ValueField="{description}" />
    </DataBindings>

</asp:TreeView>
```

How i can generate it from .aspx.cs ?

Comment: Don't you have to wrap your `SiteMapNodes` in a `SiteMap` block?

Comment: Oh, you right! List it's mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Attributes to get the value of siteMapNode like,

```
var attr = node.Attributes["title"];
```

Comment: I often recommend using the solution in following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Comment: TreeNode(what use in solusition in up posting) class of System.Windows.Forms. I don't know how use it in asp.net / SP. Can u told me?