# How to get all the key-values of the root element using c#?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I search for a few days how to parse my xml file.
So my problem I will want to recover all the key-values of the root element .

Exemple of file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE ....... SYSTEM ".....................">
<coverage x="y1"  x2="y2"  x3="y3"  x4="y4">
    <sources>
      <source>.............</source>
    </sources>
    .....
<\coverage>
```

Here, i will want to Recover all the value of "coverage" : x1 and his value , x2 and his value, x3 and his value x3...
I have already tried using "XmlReader" with all the tutorial i have could find but it still does not work.
All tutorials I've could tried, recover a value in a certain node (tag), but never all the values of the root element.

Maybe a tutorial with this same problem already exist but i haven't found him.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Look at recursive method on following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `XElement` and do this.

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(input);

var results = element.Attributes()
                     .Select(x=> 
                             new 
                             {
                                 Key = x.Name, 
                                 Value = (string)x.Value
                             });
```

**Output**

```
{ Key = x, Value = y1 }
{ Key = x2, Value = y2 }
{ Key = x3, Value = y3 }
{ Key = x4, Value = y4 }
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m6vRmh)

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Use System.Xml namespace
        //Load the XML into an XmlDocument object
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(strPathToXmlFile); //Physical Path of the Xml File
        //or
        //xDoc.LoadXml(strXmlDataString); //Loading Xml data as a String

        //In your xml data - coverage is the root element (DocumentElement)
        XmlNode rootNode = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        //To get all the attributes and its values 
        //iterate thru the Attributes collection of the XmlNode object (rootNode)
        foreach (XmlAttribute attrib in rootNode.Attributes)
        {
            string attributeName = attrib.Name; //Name of the attribute - x1, x2, x3 ...
            string attributeValue = attrib.Value; //Value of the attribute

            //do your logic here 
        }

        //if you want to save the changes done to the document
        //xDoc.Save (strPathToXmlFile); //Pass the physical path of the xml file

        rootNode = null;
        xDoc = null;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wanted to try your code, but I get the error "(407) Proxy Authentication Required"), I think (I'm even pretty sure) it's because we have a proxy. So, I will continue with the previous solution, but thank you anyway for your answer.