# XML, deserialize

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've an xml document like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <myassembly name="t1" folder="1">
        <myassembly name="t1.1" folder="0" />
        <myassembly name="t1.2" folder="0">
            <myassembly name="t1.2.1" folder="0"/>
        </myassembly>
        <myassembly name="t2" folder="0"/>
        <myassembly name="t3" folder="0">
            <myassembly name="t3.1" folder="0"/>
            <myassembly name="t3.2" folder="0"/>
        </myassembly>
    </myassembly>
</data>
```

And two classes to read the xml data:

```
class data{
    [XmlElement("myassembly")]
    MyAssembly myassembly;
}

class MyAssembly{

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    string name;

    [XmlAttribute("folder")]
    string folder;

    [XmlArrayItem("myassembly")]
    MyAssembly[] myassembly;
}
```

I want to have this array list structure:

```
data:
    assembly:
        -name: t1
        -folder: 1
        -myassembly[4]:
            [0]-name: t1.1
            [0]-folder: 0
            [0]-myassembly: null
            [1]-name: t1.2
            [1]-folder: 0
            [1]-myassembly: [4]
                [0]-name: t1.2.1
                [0]-folder: 0
                [0]-myassembly: null
            [2]-name: t2
            [2]-folder: 0
            [2]-myassembly: null
            [3]-name: t3
            [3]-folder: 0
            [3]-myassembly: [2]
                [0]-name: t3.1
                [0]-folder: 0
                [0]-myassembly: null
                [1]-name: t3.2
                [1]-folder: 0
                [1]-myassembly: null
```

But: with my attributes, i can't get this array list.
I hope, I have described it sufficiently.

regard
raiserle

Comment: sorry, c#, i've updated this question.

Comment: Some code that shows what you have tried that is not working would go a long way to helping.

Comment: I have tried this with some ``Xml-Attributes``

Comment: Right, that is apparent from your classes provided. What you do not have is the code you use to open and deserialize the xml document, the code that uses those classes.

Comment: See recursive code at following posting.  I have recommended this code lots of times : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) as seems likely, you have the following issues:

1. `XmlSerializer` only serializes **`public`** types and members.  All of your types and members are private.
2. The `public MyAssembly[] myassembly` member of `MyAssembly` needs to be marked with [`[XmlElement("myassembly")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx).  This indicates that the array should be serialized as a sequence of elements named `<myassembly>` *without* an outer container element.  By default an outer container element is used when serializing a collection.

Thus your classes should be (converting public fields to properties):

```
public class data
{
    [XmlElement("myassembly")]
    public MyAssembly myassembly { get; set; }
}

public class MyAssembly
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("folder")]
    public string folder { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("myassembly")]
    public MyAssembly[] myassembly { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can serialize and deserialize using these extension methods:

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString)
    {
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, bool omitStandardNamespaces = false)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = null;
        if (omitStandardNamespaces)
        {
            ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
        }           
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    " }; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()).Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Using them as follows:

```
var data = xmlString.LoadFromXML<data>();
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S3BEIT).