# Parsing XML to C# class

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I've been using the `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` and `StreamReader` with success for a while now and I've been able to convert Xml into c# class without a problem. But I've found a different kind of Xml file and I can not find any example on how to parse it.

Usually, the Xml files that I find are something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Signal xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable>
         <SignalName>refreshSettings</SignalName>
         <Type>X</Type>
         <Address>1</Address>
         <DefaultValue>0</DefaultValue>
         <Function>Settings, General</Function>
         <Version>3.0</Version>
         <Description>Refresh Page</Description>
     </variable>
```

But now, I found a xml that I need to parse that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configData format="Users" version="2016">
    <Object type="Users">
        <Attribute name="Comment"></Attribute>
        <Attribute name="EnableSending">Yes</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="MinPasswordLength">1</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="MinDigitsInPassword">0</Attribute>
        <Object type="UsersFolder">
            <Attribute name="Name">Users</Attribute>
            <Attribute name="Comment">This folder contains the configured users.</Attribute>
            <Object type="User">
                <Attribute name="Name">admin</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="Title">Admin User</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="UserDescription">User with access level Admin.</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="Comment">User for testing to log in with access level Admin. </Attribute>
                <Attribute name="Password">123</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="TimeOut">01:00:00</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="AccessLevel">Admin</Attribute>
            </Object>
```

Any idea on how I could parse this?

I tried something like this:

**ConfigData.cs**:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class ConfigData
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Users")]
    public Users[] Users { get; set; }
}
```

**Users.cs**:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Users
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string EnableAlarmSending { get; set; }
    public string MinPasswordLength { get; set; }
    public string MinDigitsInPassword { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("UsersFolder")]
    public UsersFolder[] usersFolder { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("GroupsFolder")]
    public GroupsFolder[] groupsFolder { get; set; }
}
```

**UsersFolder.cs**:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class UsersFolder
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("User")]
    public User[] User { get; set; }
}
```

etc.

and then in some **logic class file**:

```
public void readDataFromXML(ref ConfigData data, string filepath)
{
    try
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader1 = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(data.GetType()); /* Read the XML file. */
        StreamReader file1 = new StreamReader(filepath); /* Deserialize the content of the file into a Book object. */
        data = (ConfigData)reader1.Deserialize(file1); /* Temporario deve carregar na classe correcta */
        file1.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error Parsing Data From XML");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**called by**:

```
public string buildAreasString()
{
    ConfigData data = new ConfigData();
    readDataFromXML(ref data, UsersXmlPath);
    (...)
    return areasString;
}
```

which gives me the data object with a null Users. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) as this is what it was designed for.

Comment: Maybe use a recursive methods like code on this posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp