# How to loop all XML attributes without knowing the element

Tags: c#, xml

How do i loop all xml attribute without knowing the element name

here is my sample xml

```
<dd l="11243" t="641" r="11653" b="1004">
  <para l="11276" t="768" r="11620" b="941" alignment="left" spaceBefore="79" lsp="exactly" lspExact="273" language="en">
    <ln l="11342" t="768" r="11554" b="941" baseLine="939" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="1250" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="19" foreColor="545766">
      <wd l="11342" t="768" r="11554" b="941">
        <ch l="11342" t="768" r="11453" b="936">4</ch>
        <ch l="11472" t="768" r="11554" b="941" conf="10">3</ch>
      </wd>
    </ln>
  </para>
</dd>
```

and here is my code

```
XDocument columndoc = XDocument.Parse(reader);
foreach (var node in columndoc.Descendants("para").ToList())
{
}
```

but i don't want to loop all elements and read its l, t,r,b tag.

so how can i loop using its attribute. thank you

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Use a recursive algorithm like this posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just omit the `"para"` argument from `Descendants()` - that will obtain all the descendant elements. You can then call [`Attributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348016(v=vs.110).aspx) (which in this case is an extension method on `IEnumerable<XElement>`) to obtain all the attributes from all those elements.

```
var allAttributes = doc.Descendants().Attributes().ToList();
```