# How to use value Property in Treeview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, treeview, nodes

I want to add  Value property to all nodes in my Treeview and compare the Treeview with the xml file using value of the nodes. Can someone please provide a code snippet or something that will help me do this?

Comment: Please take a moment to read this- [MCVE]. You have to format your question accordingly so that people can help.

Comment: I recommend the following posting a lot : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp