# iterating XmlDocument with xpath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

**How do we iterate an XmlDocument using an xpath?**

I'm attempting to return a list of nodes by xpath:

```
    public static List<string> Filter(string xpath, string input, string ns, string nsUrl)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input); //i believe this unescapes the string
        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace(ns, nsUrl);
        var links = new List<string>();
        var nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath, namespaceManager);
        using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(stream))
        {
            reader.Namespaces = false;
            doc.Load(reader);
        }
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.InnerText))
            {
                continue;
            }
            links.Add(node.InnerText);
        }

        return links;
    }
```

however, the count is always 0 !

I'm using this xpath. notice how i am using only 1 namespace:

```
/ns0:Visit/ns0:DocumentInterface/ns0:Documents/ns0:Document/ns0:BinaryData
```

The header of the file looks like this:

```
<ns0:Visit xmlns:ns0="http://NameSpace.ExternalSchemas.Patient"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

I'm certain that I am using the right xpath because I tested it against my payload:

[image]

I'm calling the function this way:

```
var links = Filter(xpath, xml, "ns0", "http://NameSpace.ExternalSchemas.Patient");
```

**How do we iterate an XmlDocument using an xpath? Perhaps the XmlDocument should be an XDocument instead?**

Comment: perhaps i need to add this namespace as well? `xsi`

Comment: FYI People tend not to use these objects any more, it's far more modern to use `XDocument` instead.

Comment: that would be totally fine as well

Comment: Do not use a stream.  Instead : StringReader reader = new StringReader(input).

Comment: @jdweng cool! can you show me an example please

Comment: I was referring to following :  StringReader stream = new StringReader(input);  If you want to iterate the xml see following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp