# How to import XML data into DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm new to c# and trying to inport a XML file into DataGrid but so far I managed to import only the columns header but not the data inside the nodes. I will not know at runtime what kind of data will be loaded from the xml it can be anything but the example below is the overall structure that everything follows.

I have tried looking for answers for my problem but everything I get is for DataGridView which I am not using here so all the searches came up with more information about that than what I am looking to do. Any help will be greatly appriciated. The depth of the tags can very from 1 to 40 or more.

My XMLdata looks like this:

```
<Details>
 <Record>
  <Username>name</Username>
  <FirstName>firstname</FirstName>
  <LastName>lastname</LastName>
  etc
   .
   .
   .
 </Record>
</Details>
```

***My Xaml***

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DetailsGridTemplate" AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          Height="380" Width="430" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0.4,0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}">
</DataGrid>
```

***My import code***

```
private void InitGridFromXML(string xmlPath)
{
    var data = XElement.Load(xmlPath);

    // Set Grid data to row nodes (NOTE: grid = DataGrid member)
    var elements = data.Elements("Item");
    DetailsGridTemplate.ItemsSource = elements;

    // Create grid columns from node attributes.  A hashtable ensures
    // only one column per attribute since this iterates through all
    // attributes in all nodes.  This way, the grid can handle nodes with
    // mutually different attribute sets.
    var cols = new Hashtable();
    var rows = new Hashtable();
    foreach (XElement node in data.Descendants("Item"))
    {
        foreach (XElement childNode in node.Descendants())
        {
            var col = childNode.Name.LocalName;
            var row = childNode.Value; 

            // Only add col if it wasn't added before
            if (!cols.Contains(col))
            {
                // Mark col as added
                cols[col] = true;
                rows[row] = true;
                // Add a column with the title of the attribute and bind to its
                // value
                DetailsGridTemplate.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
                {
                    Header = col,

                });
                DetailsGridTemplate.Items.Add(new DataGridRow
                {
                    DataContext = row,
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Xml can be different depth of tags so saying ANYTHING can be problematic.  If you have different depths then you have to parse the xml recursively.  If the xml is always three levels deep the use the DataSet ReadXml method.  You need to be more specific with the type of xml you are using to get a good answer.

Comment: @jdweng The depth of the tags can very from 1 to 40 or more so i don't know before hand how many child nodes there be in the parent node <Record>.

Comment: do you mean the number of elements in Record being 40 or the number of nested levels of tags?  For a nested xml use a recursive method similar to this treeview solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Comment: @jdweng Yes correct so i mean the number of elements in <Record> tag can be from 1 up to 40+ so i can have 1 column ro 40+ columns. So each <Record> will be exactly 1 row of data and this can be n rows. Basically i will not know at run time how many rows and columns i will have it depends on the user what xml will load.

Comment: Then use the dataset method with is only two instructions.  Then bind to datatable[0] :             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);

Comment: @jdweng I have tried that but i couldn't get the data to display in the grid. Are you able to share an example maybe i didn't do it properly.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-an-ado-net-data-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to use [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview). You can bind an `XElement` directly to an `ItemsSource`.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.DataTable = new DataTable();
  }

  private void InitGridFromXML(string xmlPath)
  {
    var xmlEntities = XElement.Load(xmlPath).Elements().ToList();
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.AddRange(
      xmlEntities
        .FirstOrDefault()?
        .Elements()
        .Select(node => new DataColumn(node.Name.LocalName))
        .ToArray());

    foreach (XElement xElement in xmlEntities)
    {
      dataTable.Rows.Add(
        xElement.Elements()
          .Select(node => node.Value)
          .ToArray());
    }

    this.DataTable = dataTable;
  }

  private DataTable dataTable;  
  public DataTable DataTable
  {
    get => this.dataTable;
    set
    {
      this.dataTable = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}" />
  <Grid>
<Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that but the problem is i don't know how many column there will be at any given time. It can be only 1 column header it can be 40+ column header how will i manage that? I'm not expert in C# but will the code above not be only valid for 3 columns?

Comment: Ok. Please wait

Comment: Are the number of column variable? One record has 5 columns and the next 2 columns?

Comment: No the file will be loaded and each <Record> node will have the same number of columns each time it will not change. This will change if you load other xml file that will have different column but again even there if its 20 columns it will be 20 thorught the <Record> node. Are you able to initiate a chat so i can better explain?

Comment: Thank you that's what I wanted to know. Chat is only available when exeeding a number of comments. The example i posted should do it anyway.

Comment: Where did you get OnPropertyChanged i seem to be getting  an error here and thanks for your help.

Comment: I added the code. Also added `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to the `ViewModel` class signature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197448/discussion-between-quicksilver-and-bioniccode).